# Magento2.2 manually changed order increment id breaks checkout

Tags: checkout, magento2.2

I have a magento 2.2.0 based website and I manually changed the incriment id for orders to be a higher number

Now my checkout does not work and i get the below error

```
 main.CRITICAL: Exception message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4294967295' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `sequence_order_1` () VALUES ()
 Trace: #0 /var/www/html/*****.com/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(580): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('INSERT INTO `se...', Array)
#1 /var/www/html/****.com/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `se...', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/***.com/vendor/magento/module-sales-sequence/Model/Sequence.php(85): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('sequence_order_...', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/***.com/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ResourceModel/Quote.php(172): Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Sequence->getNextValue()
#4 /var/www/html/***.com/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote.php(2183): Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote->getReservedOrderId(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote))
#5 /var/www/html/***.com/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php(495): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote->reserveOrderId()
```

Now i am getting 
General error: 1467 Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine
in magento exception.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link helps you to resolve the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346934/mysql-failed-to-read-auto-increment-value-from-storage-engine

Check the datatype and length of increment Id field. Your value might be higher than what it can accommodate.